# OnLongClickListener on menu item

Tags: android, android-menu

I would to put a listener on the long click action for an item on the toolbar menu. 
I create the item

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_center"
    android:title="center"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_center_direction_100"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

And I get it in this way

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_map, menu);

    /* Set onclick listener on center icon to center at user position */
    MenuItem centering = menu.findItem(R.id.action_center);

    ImageView button = (ImageView) centering.getActionView();
    if (button == null)
        return true;

    button.setOnLongClickListener(
            new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    centerUserPosition();
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );

    return true;
}
```

But it does not work. What's the right way to do this??

Comment: you cannot set listener on `onCreateOptionsMenu` implement `onMenuItemSelected` and implement a runnable delay. AFAIK you cannot set long click listener on menu items by default android means

Answer (score 0):

You could set your own custom button to a toolbar. Then just set the onLongClickListener to this button.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="55dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

The button should be 32dp x 32dp with the actual icon being 24dp x 24dp.

```
//In your onCreate method
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mytoolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_button);
button.setOnLongClickListener(
        new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                centerUserPosition();
                return true;
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: I know I can do this. But I want to use menus.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try using the ActionProvider class, and then make it implement onLongClickListener. This link might get you started https://gist.github.com/vvakame/1460581